# Ajax POST Routes Back to Page as GET

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a form that I'm submitting via `POST` through Ajax.

The HTML.

```
<button onclick="submit_ajax()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="next_button" style="font-size: 24px">Create Student Account</button>
```

The Javascript.

```
//For submitting form data via AJAX
function submit_ajax(){
    data = {'username':$('#username').val(),'password':$('#password').val(),'confirm':$('#confirm').val(),'fname':$('#fname').val(),'lname':$('#lname').val(),'email':$('#email').val()}

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo AJAX_DIR; ?>/create_student_account.php',
        data: data,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function() {
            //AJAX success
            $('#success_fail_icon').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign lom_big_success_icon"></span>');
            $('#success_fail_message').html('Success! Student account created for ' + data['fname'] + '.');
        },
        error: function() {
            //Ajax failure
            $('#success_fail_icon').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign lom_big_fail_icon"></span>');
            $('#success_fail_message').html('Uh oh! Something went wrong.  Please try again, or contact us for assistance.');
        }
    });     
}
```

The `url` to the parser file is definitely correct.  Chrome's inspector tells me this: `XHR finished loading: POST "http://example.com/path/create_student_account.php".`

The Chrome inspector also says...

```
send    @   VM23103 jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
ajax    @   VM23103 jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
submit_ajax @   complete_account.php:362
onclick @   complete_account.php:256
```

Then, here's the weird part.  The result is that the user is redirected back to the same page, but with the values shown in the url as GET variables.  Chrome's inspector says...

```
Navigated to http://example.com/path/complete_account.php?username=vvv&password=vv&confirm=vv&fname=vv&lname=vv&email=
```

On the parser file, I'm simply tying to echo `$_POST['username']` or `$_GET['username']` then exit.  I'm getting nothing except the being directed back to the same page I submitted from with by POST variables somehow appended to the URL and displayed for all to see as GET variables.

If anyone has an idea, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show us your PHP code please?

Comment: All the PHP parsing file is doing is this: `echo $_POST['username'];
echo $_GET['username'];
exit;
`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
e.preventDefault();
return false;
```

at the end of your function and include an `e` parameter for the function.

to make sure your form does not submit.

Comment: This didn't do anything.  Same behavior.

Comment: Where and how do you call the submit_ajax() function?

Comment: `<button onclick="submit_ajax()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="next_button" style="font-size: 24px">Create Student Account</button>`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's wondering, using `return false;` **inside the onclick** was the key.

Not working: `<button onclick="submit_ajax()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="next_button" style="font-size: 24px">Create Student Account</button>`

Working: `<button onclick="submit_ajax(); return false;" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="next_button" style="font-size: 24px">Create Student Account</button>`